# My calc() to calculate a font-size using a combination of vw and integers is not resolving

Tags: css, calc

A fairly simple font-size calc() is not rendering

The actual code is:

`font-size: calc((${minSize} + ${fontSizeDifference}) * ((100vw - ${minScreenSize}) / ${screenSizeDifference}));`

This is attempting to be rendered within the css as:

`font-size: calc((12 + 4) * ((100vw - 375) / 825));` (except with a strikethrough)

I've tried adding/removing 'px' after each value and the calc itself, as well as reformatting/removing brackets and the vw value.

I'd expect the calc to modify the font size, but it is showing an 'Invalid property value' error

Comment: this part is invalid `100vw - 375`. you cannot add a number with a unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `375px`. Because 375 needs to know which format it is based on.

```css
.a {
  font-size: calc((12 + 4) * ((100vw - 375px) / 825));
}

.b {
  font-size: calc((12 + 4) * ((100vw - 1px) / 825));
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Text</div>
<div class="b">Text</div>
```